# How to display created thumbnail image in tkinter without saving it first?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I'm trying to display a thumbnail image in tkinter by saving the image in memory using `io.BytesIO()`. I'm getting `_tkinter.TclError: format error in bitmap data`. The `BitmapImage` [supports](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm) X11 bitmap image. So my question is how to convert my images to `xbm` before pass it to `BitmapImage` method?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import tkinter as tk
import os, os.path
import io

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

    img = Image.open("1.jpg")
    image_size = 256, 256
    img.thumbnail(image_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    b = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(b, 'gif')
    p = b.getvalue()
    photo = tk.BitmapImage(data=p)
    self.photo = photo
    self.imageview = tk.Label(self, image = self.photo, background="black")
    self.imageview.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Last time, I solved the problem using this code but sometimes the height of the image will get cut off.

```
    image = Image.open("1.jpg")
    basewidth = 900
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    image = image.resize((basewidth,hsize),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    self.imageview.configure(image=self.photo)
```

Comment: Why not just use `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)` ?

Comment: @acw1668 By using `img.thumbnail`, It's easy to resize the image while keeping its aspect ratio.

Comment: @RToward I did not mean not using `img.thumbnail`.  I mean that why doing the conversion to bitmap because `img` is already what you need.